# why bootstrap navbar menu is not collapsing?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

The collapse is not working. i am using Bootstrap 3 and angularjs. here is my code:

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-header">
                <button class="navbar-toggle pull-left" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navHeaderCollapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>  
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>  
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>    
        </button>
            <span class="navbar-brand">Refat Rafi</span>

        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navHeaderCollapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navHeaderCollapse">
                <li><a href="!#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="!#">Education</a></li>
                <li><a href="!#">About Me</a></li>
                <li><a href="!#">Education</a></li>
                <li><a href="!#">Skills</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>

    </div> 

  </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Refatrafi/0ec0zw96/

here is my added script in the body tag

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I have searched lots of previous discussion in stack overflow on this topic but could not find any solution.

Comment: isn't that jquery too old? bootstrap 3.3.4 requires 1.9. checkout its bower.json

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use the collapse plugin [http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse]

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
  Button with data-target
</button>
```

See the use of attributes `data-target` and `data-toggle`.

Also, I don't know what you are doing but I do not use Bootstrap javascripts. It will fit better into AngularJS if you use a port like AngularUI or AngularStrap.

Answer (score 0):

This is works fine  **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/sheshu036/mhsatsqu/1/)**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
   <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" 
         data-target="#example-navbar-collapse">
         <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Refat Rafi</a>
   </div>
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="example-navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
         <li class="active"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Education</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Education</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Skills</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>

</nav>
```

Comment: you need add bootstrap 3 js and css